# Java newbie while loop

Tags: loops, while-loop

I'm baffled, why doesn't the following code print anything? (2)

```
public class Testwhileloop {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i == 1);
    {
        i = i + 1; 
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You have a semicolon after the while loop, so it terminates there. Rather, the block after the while loop is considered separate.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the following statement

`while (i == 1);`

The ; at the end puts the code in an endless loop. If you remove it, the println statement will execute.